# Would an app developed using Tauri, be difficult to functional test using playwright?

Tags: angular, webdriver, playwright, webview2, tauri

The developers of one of the apps I am functional testing are moving away from  Electron (NODEJS) + Angular (JS) to WebView2 (.NET) + Angular (JS) by using Tauri 1.5. We have a functional test suite written using Playwright for the app developed using  Electron (NODEJS) + Angular (JS). It was raised that Playwright may not be used to test the functionality once the app is built using Tauri.

I believe irrespective of how the app is being built, the desktop app can be functionally tested using the same playwright framework we already have. I looked around and Googled, but I could not find any information about that.

Can there be such limitations when it comes to functional testing? Isn't that the limitations come in when the code is unit tested while building?

**UPDATE:**

A bit of search taught me that Playwright would only work with the desktop apps that are built with Electron. Electron uses Chromium as its rendering engine, which is similar to how Playwright interacts with browsers.
Since my app is built using Tauri, and its underlying technologies differ from Electrons, Playwright may not support Tauri yet. Has anyone tried this combination yet?

Comment: Well, when started, this app opens up a webview, So works as a web browser.

Comment: There's a pure WebKit flavor of the Playwright – https://www.npmjs.com/package/playwright-webkit
This should work better with Tauri, because it's based on top of the WebKit and not Chromium unlike Electron.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really harder, but that will depend on whether you do strange things in your tests or not.

There is an official section in the documentation using selenium[1][2], which you can use as a starting point for your playwright tests.

Can you post at least one medium-sized test?

Also, if you ever want to contribute to Tauri, writing a `with playwright` section of the documentation seems like the perfect start for you, after you port your first tests.

[1] https://jonaskruckenberg.github.io/tauri-docs-wip/development/testing.html#with-selenium
[2] https://beta.tauri.app/guides/test/webdriver/example/selenium/

Comment: A bit of search taught me that the Playwright would only work with the desktop apps that are built with Electron. Electron uses Chromium as its rendering engine, which is similar to how Playwright interacts with browsers. 
Since my app is built using Tauri, and its underlying technologies differ from Electrons, Playwright may not support Tauriyet. Has anyone tried this combination yet?